# PHP validation link to next page

Tags: php, forms, validation, hyperlink, refresh

I have an HTML form page which I post back to itself in order to perform some PHP Validation.

Once posted back to itself and the validation passes, I direct the page to the next link using the string:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://www.website.com/planning/page2.php\">";
```

When using this however the page refreshes on itself before going to the next page (page2.php) this means the page flashes again whilst performing validation then redirects. How can I make this not 'flash' when performing the validation?

my validation is as follows:

```
//validation
if(isset($_POST['loadid'])){
$errors = array();
$load=$_POST['loadid'];

if (empty($load)){
$errors[]='<strong><font color=red>Please select a load number</font></strong>';
}


if (!empty($errors)) {
foreach ($errors as $error) {
    echo $error."<br>";
    }}
    else {
        echo "Population accurate";
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://www.website.com/planning/page2.php\">"; 
        $_SESSION['sessionloadid']=$_POST['loadid'];

}
}
```

Thanks for the help,
Ryan Smith

Comment: Have you tried to remove the redirect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flash results because you're doing the redirect "inside the browser". That means, the browser needs to load your HTML and then already starts to display it.

Then the browser sees it should redirect, resets the window (flash) and does the redirect.

You can prevent this by doing the redirect already with HTTP headers:

```
$_SESSION['sessionloadid']=$_POST['loadid'];
$uri = 'http://www.website.com/planning/page2.php';
header('Location: '.$uri);
printf('<a href="%s">Moved.</a>', $uri);
exit;
```

instead of:

```
echo "Population accurate";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://www.website.com/planning/page2.php\">"; 
$_SESSION['sessionloadid']=$_POST['loadid'];
```

A browser processes HTTP headers before starting to display the page, it then sees the redirect and redirects (often automatically). If the browser does not redirect automatically, a short "Moved." message is displayed, so the user can navigate to the new location by clicking the link.

See as well the [`http_redirect`](http://php.net/http_redirect) function, that offers more to make redirects with PHP. If you don't have the extension available, the function documentation shows multiple points you should take care about when doing redirects with PHP:

- Using an absolute URI.
- Offering a HTTP body.
- Specifying the redirect code (301, 302, ...).
- Exiting the script.

If you don't have that function available, I suggest you write one that does the same, so you can easily do redirects within your application.

Comment: is correct here +1.  You can't rely on `<meta http-equiv="refresh"...>` because some browsers may have that turned off.  The above `header()` call will issue a `302 Found` to the browser and the browser will redirect to `$uri` immediately.   It shouldn't be necessary to print the `Moved` link after issuing a header redirect, but might as well in case the browser has a maximum number of redirects set to 0 for some odd reason.

Comment: @Yzmir Ramirez: A browser might have automatic redirects for location headers disabled as well, just noting to keep that in mind.

Comment: Might be worth adding the response code you want to send with the `header()` function (i.e. whether it's a 301 or, in this case, a 303 redirect).

Comment: Hi @hakre, thanks for the advice. I get the error

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/user/public_html/lanning/page2.php:25) in /home/user/public_html/lanning/page2 on line 31

Line 31 in my code is:
header('Location: '.$uri); 

Any advice. is this because the POST action points to itself in order to perform validation? what is the work around?